# Phrasing of 'Duplicate' Close Reason

Tags: discussion

We currently have a question gathering close votes as a duplicate. [Short story about a young boy living in South Africa during Apartheid](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/19787/short-story-about-a-young-boy-living-in-south-africa-during-apartheid)

The close reason specifically says 'This question has been asked before', but in this instance it hasn't, it's been asked *since* @Luke's question.

Is there scope to make the wording of the 'Duplicate' close reason inclusive of such a scenario? And if there is scope, is it something we should do?

Perhaps just, 'The same question already has an answer'?

Comment: It is a fairly common and accepted practice across the network to close an older question as duplicate of a newer one.  It applies if the newer question contains more detail or clarity and therefore is seen by the community as more deserving of staying open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wording while closing is a bit weird for cases like this, yes.

However, the public-facing reason when it's actually closed is worded differently:

[image: This question already has answers here]

I don't know if it's possible to change the wording in the close dialog, but I don't think so - that's the standard wording across the network. That wording isn't what's shown to users after closure, though.

Comment: Fair enough, it's just a bit weird when you see it in the review queueue and it makes you wonder if you fell into a wormhole.

Comment: From main meta: [Should I vote to close a duplicate question, even though it's much newer, and has more up to date answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147643/1017231)